# How to delete a Custom Content Type post with REST API with crocoblock (Jet Engine)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, jet-engine

I have been trying to delete a custom content type post from frontend, but I need it to be done on the listing grid for better UX so that people don't have to press 4 times just to delete a post.

I tried some things, but I don't have the programming knowlage to understand how to do it.